# non Abelian groups which have normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What will be the non-Abelian groups other then $S_3$ which have non-trivial normal subgroups?

Comment: Like, all of them? Precisely the nonabelian nonsimple groups. Note $A_n\triangleleft S_n$ for all $n\ge3$, not just $n=3$. And there are many more examples. Do you just want some examples?

Comment: Ya I need some examples at least 2 or 3

Comment: For homework? Have you tried looking through the nonabelian groups (symmetric, dihedral, matrix groups) you know and finding normal subgroups in them?

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks

Comment: @user148628, take any dihedral group and consider the subgroup generated by a single rotation.  Also, as blue stated, $A_n$ is always normal in nontrivial symmetric groups.

Comment: Thanks for the help Hansen

Comment: Try the group of upper triangular matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Pick your favorite non-trivial abelian group $A$, then $G=S_3 \times A$ is non-abelian and $\{(1)\}\times A$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup.